# print each char of string array with double pointer in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, char, pointer-to-pointer

The program is expected to print each char of the string array.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    const char* numbers[10]{"One", "Too",   "Three", "Four", "Five",
                "Six", "Seven", "Eight", "Nine", "Zero"};

    /*  This version did not work. Why?
           for (const char** ptr = numbers; *ptr != nullptr; *ptr++) {
                const char* pos = *ptr;
                while (*pos != '\0')
                    cout << *(pos++) << " ";
            }
    */
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < sizeof(numbers) / sizeof(numbers[0]); ++i)
    {
        const char* pos = numbers[i];
        while(*pos != '\0')
            printf("%c ", *(pos++));
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I am aware that my code is a mixture of C++17 and C(in a transition from C to C++, `nullptr`, `cout` are two examples), but not sure the first `for-loop` with

```cpp
for (const char** ptr = numbers; *ptr != nullptr; *ptr++)
```

is correct or not. What's wrong with it?
Is there a "best practice" to looping thru array of string(char array , not string object yet), especially with the double pointer I'd like to catch, in this case? Thanks!

Comment: Consider putting together a [mcve] that actually compiles.

Comment: Thanks! You are really fast! Post has been edited with full code.

Comment: Arrays have length, they are not ended by any marker such as NULL or alike. Add an approriate ending marker by yourself.

Comment: The term "double pointer" is ambiguous, and most accurately refers to type `double*`. I suggest using the term "pointer to pointer" instead (as suggested by the [pointer-to-pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pointer-to-pointer) tag description).

Comment: I read comments about "pointer-to-pointer" in other places too. I'll try to use as suggested.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two things -

First, in this loop expression, you don't need to dereference the `ptr` after incrementing it - `*ptr++`.

```
for (const char** ptr = numbers; *ptr != nullptr; *ptr++)
                                                  ^^
```

`*ptr++` will be grouped as - `*(ptr++)`, which means, (post)increment the `ptr` and dereference the result of (post)increment. It should be just `ptr++`, as we need the `ptr` pointer to point to next element in the `numbers` array after executing the loop body.

Second, if your loop condition is checking for `nullptr` then the array, which loop is iterating, should have `nullptr` as a marker to indicate the end of array and you need to increase the size of array as well to adjust end marker:

```
     const char* numbers[11] {"One", "Too", "Three", "Four", "Five",
                              "Six", "Seven", "Eight", "Nine", "Zero", nullptr};
```

With the above mentioned changes, the following loop should print the `numbers` array strings:

```
       for (const char** ptr = numbers; *ptr != nullptr; ptr++) {
           const char* pos = *ptr;

           while (*pos != '\0')
               cout << *(pos++) << " ";

           cout << "\n";
       }
```

Since, you have added a new element in the `numbers` array to mark end of array, be cautious, in the second loop, you are doing `sizeof(numbers)/sizeof(numbers[0])` to get the array size and it will give `11` and second loop will end up accessing the `nullptr` which will be undefined behaviour. Either subtract `1` from `sizeof` result in loop condition or add a check `pos != nullptr` before processing it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the elaboration on ptr++. I take yours as answer.

Answer (score 0):

In your first loop you a looking for ‘nullptr’ in your array, but you didn’t put it there.

You are reading uninitialized garbage after you array.

I suggest to use std::vector or std::array

Comment: Thanks for pointing out 'nullptr' not in the array. Added NULL to the array, for( const char** p2 = numbers; *p2 != NULL; *p2++) { ...}  still segfault.

Answer (score 0):

Try these edits and see what happens

```
const char* numbers[11]{"One", "Too", "Three", "Four", "Five", 
                                    "Six", "Seven", "Eight", "Nine", "Zero", NULL};
```

and

```
;i < sizeof(numbers)/sizeof(numbers[0])-1;
```

in the second `for` loop

Basically `*ptr` points to the beginning of the respective string. But after last one, it goes out-of-bound. If you really have to compare to `nullptr` the above is the way to do.

**EDIT**

Yeah, in addition to the above, `ptr` should be incremented instead of `*ptr`. `*ptr` will be traversing over the string rather than that array.

Comment: The pure C part is working. But my question is about the for-loop part with double pointer that I am struggling with.

Comment: @Yifangt Did you tried with the edits ? The `-1`  after `sizeof` will not change anything. It is there because there is 1 extra element in the array now.

Comment: Yes, I tried the -1 for the commented part. Still segfault. I think the problem is with the *ptr++ in the for loop, cf answer by H.S. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @Yifangt Yeah I missed that. Also, -1 is not for the commented loop but the second loop